# postfix evaluation , why is the push function not updating the top of stack variable?

Tags: c++, stack, postfix-notation

when giving input "53+",it is pushing 5 and updates tos to 0 from '-1' but when the function is invoked for the second time, it pushes 3 but tos is still 0 , not 1. please help.

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

int push(int tos, int x);
int pop(int tos);

int st[50];
int tos=-1;

int main()
{
    char str[30];
    int r,k,v1,v2,i;

    cin>>str;
    for(i=0;str[i]!='\0';i++)
    {
        if(str[i]!='*'&&str[i]!='-'&&str[i]!='+'&&str[i]!='/')
        {
            k=str[i]-'0';
            push(tos,k);
        }
        else
        {
            if(tos==-1||tos==0) 
                cout<<"enter correct format";
            else
            {
                v1=pop(tos);
                v2=pop(tos);
                switch(str[i])
                {
                case '*': r=v1*v2;
                    push(tos,r);
                    break;
                case '+': r=v1+v2;
                    push(tos,r);
                    break;
                case '-': r=v1-v2;
                    push(tos,r);
                    break;
                case '/': r=v1/v2;
                    push(tos,r);
                    break;
                default: 
                    cout<<"invalid";
                }
            }
        }
    }
    r=pop(tos);
    cout<<endl<<r;
    return 0;
}
int push(int tos, int x)
{
    if (tos==50-1)
        cout<<"overflow"<<endl;
    else
    {
        tos++;
        st[tos]=x;
        cout<<endl<<"pushed"<<tos<<st[tos];
    }
}

int pop(int tos)
{ 
    int z;
    if(tos==-1)
        cout<<"underflow";
    else
    {
        z=st[tos];
        tos-=1;
    }
    return z;
}
```

when giving input "53+",it is pushing 5 and updates tos to 0 from '-1' but when the function is invoked for the second time, it pushes 3 but tos is still 0 , not 1.

Comment: Voting to close as a typo.  You need to pass by reference in order for the function to modify what is passed to it. `int push(int tos, int x)` -> `int push(int& tos, int x)` and `int pop(int tos)` -> `int pop(int& tos)`

Comment: This seems like an excellent time to [learn how to debug your programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: The indentation here is like a roller-coaster. Can you try and straighten that out so we can follow what you're trying to do?

Comment: Turn on warnings, you have an uninitialized variable and a function that does not return a value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `push()` and `pop()` functions receives `tos` by value, so any changes they make to `tos` are not reflected outside the functions.

One solution is to pass `tos` by reference, e.g.

```
int push(int &tos, int x)
{
    // Any changes to tos are now reflected in the variable passed in.
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The basic problem is that you have two variables called `tos`.

First is this global variable.

```
int tos=-1;
int main()
{
```

And then you have another variable called `tos` in the `push` function

```
int push(int tos, int x)
{
```

At the moment your code changes the local variable, but does not change the global variable, hence the confusion. Having local and global variables with the same name is asking for trouble. In this case I recommend that you remove the local variable. The `st` array is manipulated as a global, so it seems logical for the `tos` variable to be the same.

```
int push(int x)
{
```

You will have to change each call to push as well

```
                       push(tos,r);
```

becomes

```
                       push(r);
```

etc. etc.

Then you need to make exactly the same change to the `pop` function which has exactly the same problem.